# Java library to scan image using a scanner

Tags: java

In my project I want to scan an image using a scanner. Which Java library could I use to grab the scanned image from a scanner?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if there is any open source software for this, but [JTwain](http://asprise.com/product/jtwain/) seems to be able to do what you need.